# Display image position based on mouse click coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I start with a blank page, and the user is supposed to click anywhere on the page to make an image pop up. I'm trying to display an image at the exact coordinates of where a user clicks within a page.
I am able to get an image to pop up in the corner whenever/wherever the user clicks. I am also able to gather the x and y coordinates of where the mouse clicks within a page, but in making those coordinates the coordinates of the image, I'm having trouble. With the code I have below, when the user clicks anywhere within the window, the image of a snowball appears in the upper left hand corner, and the x coordinates of the click are displayed. (Clicking more changes the x coordinate displayed with each click). My question is, how do I get the snowball to appear at the click coordinates?

```
<head>
<script>
    document.onclick = userClicked;
    function userClicked() {

        var x = event.clientX;
        var y = event.clientY;
        document.getElementById("xCoord").innerHTML=x;
        document.getElementById("snowballAppear").style.display = '';
    }

</script>

<div class "container">
    <div class "picture">
        <img alt="snowballAppear" id="snowballAppear" style="display: none" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/pottermore/images/9/99/Snowball-lrg.png/revision/latest?cb=20130412122815"/>
    </div>
</div>

</head>
```

Comment: May want to use [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/). Click the `view source` link. Of course, you should use external JavaScript, unlike the example. External JavaScript will allow the Client to cache your script, making load times faster next time they visit your site, assuming they don't clear their cache.

Comment: You properly don't want to put your `<div>`s in `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS element "left" for X and "top" for Y. Make sure to have a "position: absolute;" css style in the image.

Basically, in code:

```
function userClicked() {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    var snowball = document.getElementById("snowballAppear");
    snowball.style.display = '';
    snowball.style.position = 'absolute';
    snowball.style.left = x + 'px';
    snowball.style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mxq629ng/

You might want to subtract half the height / width of the image from the X and Y to center it around the mouse.

EDIT: Addition as some comments came back; you might want to add the "event" as a passable argument in the userClicked function. The click event will forward that "event" variable into your function. This will make it work in many major browsers (somehow it works in V8). Check this Fiddle and it should work in most major browsers; https://jsfiddle.net/mxq629ng/1/

Comment: That might be his next question :) I'm quite sure we both know why.

Comment: So can you please explain it to me?

Comment: event will not be known. If the JS engine of chrome made any sense it wouldn't even work there. The event from the mouse click should be forwarded into the userClicked function, and from there the "event" variable can be used. Next to that it won't work in older IE versions.

Comment: So you are saying that i should write my function as this: `function userClicked(event) {`?

Comment: This will make it work in SpiderMonkey and V8, yes. Haven't tested other engines but most browsers nowadays use one of those engines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Unfortunately this didn't work for me :( The snowball straight up didn't appear at all.

Comment: Did you check the comments dev-null wrote? Quite sure it has something to do with that :) Refresh this page if you will. There have been some updates.

Comment: I have another quick question. Right now the snowball moves around with every click. How would I go about generating a new snowball with every click?

Comment: You can create new HTML elements by using document.write or other methods. There's tons of solutions for that, just google for "javascript dynamic element create" and you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to position the img element:

Dont't forget to pass in the event to your function

```
function userClicked(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    document.getElementById("xCoord").innerHTML=x;
    document.getElementById("snowballAppear").style.display = '';
    // fixed position - The element is positioned relative to the browser window
    document.getElementById("snowballAppear").style.position = "fixed";
    // px from top of browser
    document.getElementById("snowballAppear").style.top  = y + "px";
    // px from left of browser
    document.getElementById("snowballAppear").style.left = x + "px";
}
```